# Data validation in Excel- all values in comma-delimited list within cell range

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, csv, data-validation

I have a reference table of memos and some information about them, including what other memos they reference and are referenced by. I want to make a data validation rule that will appear red if any of the values in the comma-delimited list of references aren't in my list of memos (in other words, we're missing information or the user may have made a typo). Any number of other memos may be referenced. The memo numbers for each entry are in column A, the references are in column G. Headings row A, data in following rows, to be added onto regularly.

A............G

LF100009.......400 <--red

HS100011.......

RT100012.......LF100009

LA100015.......LF100009, RT100012

ME100020.......HS100011, RT1000012, LA100015 <--red

KE100050.......LA100011, LA100015 <--red

[image: screen snip of workbook]

Comment: Can you post a sample workbook? Your example above does not seem to align with your question.

Comment: sorry I don't see where to add an attachment? @Chris

Comment: added a screenshot of an example workbook page, but for confidentiality reasons it's still a bunch of made up data, just formatted the way I want it, in the right places, with reasons for why something gets highlighted.

Comment: Conditional formatting or data validation?

Comment: conditional formatting for the background in red, although if data validation is able to be done while still allowing multiple references for each memo that would be awesome, too. I just figured that wasn't possible.

Comment: Is there a max number of references that a cell in column G can contain? i.e. in your example the max number of references is 3

Comment: @Chris no, the revisions to memos could even refer to ones originally made later. Ones with a lot of revisions are more likely to cross-reference more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not at all elegant, but this would work for up to 3 references. 
You could combine with conditional formatting as required or put into a helper column.

```
=IF(IF(IF(G2="",TRUE,LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",""))+1)=TRUE,1,
IF(IF(G2="",TRUE,LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",""))+1)=1,COUNTIF(A:A,G2),
IF(IF(G2="",TRUE,LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",""))+1)=2,SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A:A,LEFT(G2,FIND(",",G2)-1)))*(COUNTIF(A:A,MID(G2,FIND(",",G2)+2,LEN(G2))))),
IF(IF(G2="",TRUE,LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",""))+1)=3,SUMPRODUCT((COUNTIF(A:A,LEFT(G2,FIND(",",G2)-1)))*(COUNTIF(A:A,MID(G2,FIND(",",G2)+2,LEN(G2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(G2,",","@",IF(G2="",TRUE,LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",""))+1)-1))-1)))*(COUNTIF(A:A,MID(G2,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(G2,",","@",IF(G2="",TRUE,LEN(G2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(G2,",",""))+1)-1))+2,LEN(G2))))),
FALSE
))))=1,TRUE)
```

Comment: This works so far. Would I just continue that pattern if I needed to have it work for more references? Also, it looks like a part of that is taking out the commas. They're not necessary, would it be better if they weren't there? Also, I was planning to have effectively a go to hyperlink as a separate column, but just in case it works, would this formula work if the memos and/or the references were hyperlinks?

Comment: Best to take the VBA approach mention below as the above formula will be too difficult to modify if you have more than 3 references. However, the formula approach will also work fine if you wish to implement hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

And here is a UDF that puts a TRUE / FALSE value in a helper cell.
The formula would look like `=testReferences(G2,A:A,", ")`

The following code gets pasted into VBA editor. It works for unlimited references.

```
Function testReferences(text As Range, list As Range, delimiter As String)
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim found As Boolean

    If text = "" Then
        found = True
    Else
        arr = Split(text, delimiter)            
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(list, arr(i)) = 1 Then
                found = True
            Else
                found = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    testReferences = found
End Function
```

Comment: I saved as a macro-enabled excel file (it wasn't before), and put it in the first line as you showed, but it's giving me a #Name? error for each entry. Here's a screenshot. @Chris [link](http://imgur.com/CMPKTWE)

Comment: Did you put the code into the vba editor first before saving the file? This link here may help - http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-User-Defined-Function-in-Microsoft-Excel